# Can a crack in an electric oil-filled radiator be (relatively safely) repaired?

Tags: repair, appliances, radiator, electric-heat

I was following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8yGzC9kgH4) (found on [this Fixya forum](https://www.fixya.com/support/t15400405-wont_turn_makes_buzzing_noise)) to repair a bad capacitor in a broken Kenwood oil radiator that would only make a buzzing noise when powered on.  However, when I got the front assembly off of the radiator, I found that there was *also* a crack in the portion of the body of the radiator that contained the oil.  It also looked like perhaps some small amount of oil had dripped out at some point.  Picture below:

[image: image of radiator with small crack]

(I suspect this happened after getting knocked down a few times by my children.)

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can patch this crack and continue to operate it, perhaps only in circumstances in which someone is in the room to monitor it and make sure nothing goes awry.  Lowest tech would be duct tape, but maybe I could use some sort of caulk solution?  Or is this a lost cause, and I should just scrap the whole thing?

Comment: If the crack is deeper than the paint, into the metal, then replacement is the best.

Comment: I don't have any understanding of what causes oil filled electric heaters to explode, but given that it does (rarely) happen I would be very reluctant to run a damaged one.

Answer (score 2):

Take off a bit of the paint around the crack. If there's any visible damage to the metal, including rust, rather than just a crack in the paint, it's effectively trash. Repair is not worthwhile.